# selectize.setValue not working

Tags: selectize.js

I am using selectize with knockout. I want to set default values in input field. My code is:

```
var selecti = $('#select-tag').selectize({
                            valueField: 'name',
                            labelField: 'name',
                            searchField: 'name',
                            maxItems: 4,
                            create: true,
                            render: {
                                option: function (item, escape) {
                                    return '<div>' +
                                        '<span class="title">' +
                                            '<span class="name">' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' +

                                        '</span>' +
                                        '<span class="description">' + escape(item.info) + '</span>' +
                                        '<ul class="meta">' +
                                            '<li class="watchers"><span>' + escape(item.followers) + '</span> followers</li>' +
                                            '<li class="forks"><span>' + escape(item.questions) + '</span> questions asked</li>' +
                                        '</ul>' +
                                    '</div>';
                                }
                            },
                            load: function (query, callback) {
                                if (!query.length) return callback();
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/api/Tag/SearchTags?s=' + encodeURIComponent(query),
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    error: function () {
                                        callback();
                                    },
                                    success: function (res) {
                                        callback(res.slice(0, 10));
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        var sel = selecti[0].selectize;
                        sel.setValue(self.selectedTags);
                        console.log(self.selectedTags); //contains selected tags
```

The code above is not showing `selectedTags` in input field. What i am doing wrong?